# Como solucionar este error: does not name a type

Tags: c++11

Esta linea de codigo  `Doom build();` genera este error `include/Builder.h|17|error: ‘Doom’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘bool’?|` no entiendo porque. creo que se esta generando una especie de ciclo es por ello el error?

si borro esa linea funciona bien, pero necesito que el metodo `build` devuelva la clase `Doom`

```
#include "Doom.h"

class Builder
{
    public:
        std::string name;

        std::vector<std::string> attr;

        Builder(std::string name, std::vector<std::string> attr);
        Builder addElement(std::string);
        Builder addAttr(std::vector<std::string>);
        Doom build();
}
```

Mientras que la clase Doom tiene en el constructor la clase Builder

```
#include "Doom.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
Doom::Doom(Builder builder)
{

    name=builder.name;
    attr=builder.attr;
}
```

esta es la implementacion:

```
#include "Builder.h"

Builder::Builder(std::string name, std::vector<std::string> attr)
{
this->name=name;
this->attr=attr;
}

Builder Builder::addElement(std::string name){
}

Builder Builder::addAttr(std::vector<std::string> attrs){
}

Doom Builder::build(){
}
```

esta es la implementacion de la clase Doom.h

```
#ifndef DOOM_H
#define DOOM_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Builder.h"

using namespace std;

class Doom
{
public:
    Doom(Builder);
    std::string  name;
    vector<std::string>  attr;

protected:
    vector<std::string> fillBody(vector<std::string>);

private:
};
```

Comment: Cómo has definido la clase Doom en Doom.h? Porque le hace falta saber cómo está definida la clase Builder al hacer referencia a ella en el constructor. Tal vez tengas que añadir la línea `class Builder;` antes de la definición de la clase Doom. Así le dices al compilador que existe una clase Builder que estará definida más adelante, pero ya sabe que existe. Necesitaría ver cómo están los dos ficheros h el Builder.h y Doom.h, pero parece que va por ahí el tema.

Comment: @SuperG280 edite mi pregunta, puse las implementaciones

Comment: Hola. He copiado el código en un proyecto de pruebas y he tratado de compilarlo. ¿Puede ser que te falte el punto y coma tras la llave de cierre de la clase Builder en builder.h? En lo que has copiado falta y es parte del problema. Por otro lado, lo que te decía antes: Tienes que incluir la definicion de la clase Builder antes de la definición de la clase Doom en Doom.h. Basta con que añadas la línea tal cual: `class Builder;` Así le dices al compilador cuando compile la clase Doom que habrá una clase Builder y que aunque aun no la haya compilado, lo hará a continuación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include "Doom.h"

int main()
{
}
```

El siguiente fragmento de código no compilará con tu código actual. ¿Por qué? Veamos:

Lo primero que se va a encontrar el compilador es el `include`, así que localizará la cabecera `Doom.h` y reemplazará su contenido por dicha `directiva`:

```
#ifndef DOOM_H
#define DOOM_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Builder.h"

using namespace std;

class Doom
{
public:
    Doom build();
};

int main()
{
}
```

Sigue procesando el resto de includes y entonces se encuentra con el include a `Builder.h`, una vez reemplazada la directiva por el contenido de la cabecera el fichero quedará más o menos así:

```
#ifndef DOOM_H
#define DOOM_H
// Contenido cabecera <string>
// Contenido cabecera <vector>
// Contenido cabecera <iostream>

#include "Doom.h"

class Builder
{
};

using namespace std;

class Doom
{
public:
    Doom build();
};

int main()
{
}
```

Entonces volverá a intentar incluir la cabecera `Doom.h`... aquí podríamos entrar en un ciclo sin fín, ya que ambas cabeceras se incluyen mutuamente... entre otras cosas para eso existen las guardas `#ifndef ...`. El caso es que el contenido de  la cabecera `Doom.h` no se vuelve a añadir gracias a esas guardas, con lo que el archivo finalmente quedará así:

```
#ifndef DOOM_H
#define DOOM_H
// Contenido cabecera <string>
// Contenido cabecera <vector>
// Contenido cabecera <iostream>

class Builder
{
public:
    Doom build();  // <<--- Primer uso de Doom
};

using namespace std;

class Doom // <<--- Declaración de Doom
{
};

int main()
{
}
```

Como puedes ver el problema es que el compilador se encuentra usos de un tipo que desconoce totalmente.

Para solucionar este problema  existen los *declaration forward* o declaraciones adelantas. Este resurso se puede usar siempre que no tengamos objetos del tipo en el archivo en cuestión.

Por ejemplo, si la cabecera de `Builder` es tal y como indicas en la pregunta (no has omitido variables internas ni métodos inline), esa cabecera realmente no necesita conocer los métodos de `Doom`, ni cuánto ocupa en memoria... ni tan siquiera sus posibles herencias. Solo se usa como tipo de retorno.

Como esta cabecera no declara ni usa objetos de tipo `Doom` podemos usar un *declaration forward* tranquilamente:

```
class Doom; // Declaration forward

class Builder
{
    public:
        std::string name;

        std::vector<std::string> attr;

        Builder(std::string name, std::vector<std::string> attr);
        Builder addElement(std::string);
        Builder addAttr(std::vector<std::string>);
        Doom build();
}
```

El *declaration forward* le dice al compilador que `Doom` es una clase. Es todo cuanto necesita en esta cabecera para que el código sea correcto.

Ahora bien, la implementación de `Builder` **sí que necesita** el include a `Doom.h`, ya que presumiblemente dicha implementación necesitará manipular de alguna forma objetos de tipo `Doom` y es ahí donde el compilador sí que necesitará conocer completamente la clase `Doom`.

Da la impresión que en la cabecera `Doom.h` se puede aplicar este mismo concepto para evitar la dependencia de `Builder.h`:

```
class Builder;

class Doom
{
public:
    Doom(Builder);
    std::string  name;
    vector<std::string>  attr;

protected:
    vector<std::string> fillBody(vector<std::string>);

private:
};
```

Evitar la dependencia entre cabeceras reduce el tiempo de compilación, ya que si se modifica una cabecera, todos los archivos que incluyan de forma directa o indirecta (vía otros includes) dicha cabecera deberán recompilarse aunque el cambio no les afecte en absoluto... así que este es un recurso bastante utilizado en C++.

Comment: magnifica respuesta, soluciono mi problema!!!